# Creating and writing to directories in Python with leading slash stopped working after creating tar archive

Tags: python, linux, tar

I have a Python 2.7 program running on Ubuntu that - among other things - creates a directory structure if the directories are not there, then writes files to these new directories.

It worked fine until yesterday after I created a tar archive with the program and its output files.

Then it suddenly stopped working. I did not edit the code itself.

It turns out Python - in this program as well as elsewhere and in this directory as well as elsewhere - will no longer create or write to directories with a path with a leading slash. This worked just fine before.

Trying to recreate it using os.makedirs('/tmp/2015-03-21') results in an OSError: File Exists - even though I have deleted the directories. The same thing happens if I execute this command from anywhere else in my directory structure trying to create directories that have never existed. Calling os.makedirs with any other path with a leading slash results in an OSError: Permission Denied.

If I remove the leading slash it all works fine.

I write files to these directories using a number of different methods. For all of them trying to write a file to one of these directories using a path with a leading slash produces no output. Again, omitting the leading slash everything works just fine.

What is going on?

Comment: This is indeed weird. What are the outputs  of:
`os.path.realpath('/tmp')`
`os.path.abspath('/tmp')`

Comment: By "created a tar archive", what exact commands do you mean you ran? What happens when you try to create these directories and files from the shell instead of in Python?

Comment: `@HaroldShip` `os.path.realpath('/tmp')` and `os.path.abspath('/tmp')` both output `'/tmp'`

Comment: `@DanGetz` I created the archive from the terminal, not in Python, using `tar -czf task.tar.gz somefile otherfile tmp` or I might have written `tar -czf task.tar.gz somefile otherfile \tmp`. I don't recall which.

Comment: `@DanGetz` `@HaroldShip` I am working on a VirtualBox VM btw

Comment: Read doc of **tar(1)**, as it states that it eats up the leading slashes, forcing all paths to relative (at least, i remember to read that in GNU tar doc)

Comment: @krismunk I guess I'm confused as to why running `tar` could be related to your Python program working or not working. I feel like there's something you did that you think is obvious from your description, but is not obvious to me because you didn't say it explicitly. Do you really mean to say that running the following, from a directory unrelated to your program, raises that `OSError`? `python -c "import os; os.makedirs('/tmp/2015-03-21')"`

Comment: `@LuisColorado` I realize that. Therefore, it shouldn't matter which of the two ways I called tar. Also, it still shouldn't influence Python

Comment: `@DanGetz`Yes, that is was I mean to say. I don't understand how running tar should affect Python either. I just can't think of anything else I did in between the code working and not working.